# Always return null in getting value by SAX Parser

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

Hi I'm practicing getting value from XML.
I copy it from a tutorial but I always get into the catch zone and setting text as null.
Here is the code:
MainActivity.java

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);

            /* Create a new TextView to display the parsingresult later. */
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            try {
                    /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.anddev.org/images/tut/basic/parsingxml/example.xml");

                    /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

                    /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                    /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
                    ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                    /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                    /* Parsing has finished. */

                    /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
                    ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet =
                                                                    myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

                    /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
                    tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
                    tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            /* Display the TextView. */
            this.setContentView(tv);
    }
```

}

This is the Logcat:

```
11-13 12:02:40.689: W/System.err(1061): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-13 12:02:40.749: W/System.err(1061):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
11-13 12:02:40.789: W/System.err(1061):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-13 12:02:40.789: W/System.err(1061):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-13 12:02:40.809: W/System.err(1061):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-13 12:02:40.859: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
11-13 12:02:40.859: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-13 12:02:40.879: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
11-13 12:02:40.879: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
11-13 12:02:40.952: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-13 12:02:40.952: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
11-13 12:02:40.959: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
11-13 12:02:40.959: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
11-13 12:02:41.009: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
11-13 12:02:41.029: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
11-13 12:02:41.029: W/System.err(1061):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
11-13 12:02:41.029: W/System.err(1061):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
11-13 12:02:41.099: W/System.err(1061):     at com.example.xmltestfinal1_1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
11-13 12:02:41.099: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-13 12:02:41.152: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-13 12:02:41.179: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-13 12:02:41.179: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-13 12:02:41.239: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-13 12:02:41.289: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-13 12:02:41.289: W/System.err(1061):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 12:02:41.299: W/System.err(1061):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 12:02:41.359: W/System.err(1061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-13 12:02:41.359: W/System.err(1061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 12:02:41.399: W/System.err(1061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 12:02:41.409: W/System.err(1061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-13 12:02:41.442: W/System.err(1061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 12:02:41.449: W/System.err(1061):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code and Logcat output that shows the error.

Comment: My Logcat only has this: 11-13 11:23:24.119: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Thanks. It may be helpful to call `e.printStackTrace()` inside of the catch block so that you can see (in Logcat) the precise exception that's being thrown along with the line that's responsible.

Comment: @acj Thank you :) I called e.printStackTrace and got these messages

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the network from your app's main (UI) thread, which isn't allowed in recent versions of Android. That's the reason for the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in your Logcat output. Your users might see an "Application Not Responding" warning if the network is slow, and your app may get killed as a result.

You'll want to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download and parse your XML thread in a background thread. This enables your app to interact with the user while the background thread is processing the XML data. There are plenty of `AsyncTask` tutorials on SO that can help if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

You are performing network operation within the **MAIN** Thread

Long operations should be performed in background thread like the following

1. Network Operation (Downloading Files, etc..)
2. File operations (Reading content of files, etc..)
3. complex calculations...

To make this happen. You should use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You can display the Text within the `onPostExecute()`

Additional,

If you want to set data in UI Objects from background Thread, Use `Handler` object

Answer (score 0):

` public void demoxml()

```
{ 
    AssetManager manager = getAssets();
    InputStream stream;

    try {
        XMLDOMParser parser = new XMLDOMParser();
        stream = manager.open("game.xml");
        Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Log.i("DocumentBuilder--->", "Document Building is complete--> ready for parsing");

       // Document doc = dBuilder.parse("http://myinfo.comuf.com/ram/game.xml");
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Log.i("Document--('-')->","it is open");

        //get all tabs
        NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
        int lengthq = nodeList.getLength();
        Log.i("Node length is ", ""+String.valueOf(lengthq));
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("array");
        int length = nl.getLength();
        Log.i("Node length is ", ""+String.valueOf(length));

        for(int i=0; i<length; i++ ){
            Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
           // RSSItem item = new RSSItem();

            Log.i("Main Node-->"+i+"---",currentNode.toString());

            NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
            int clength = nchild.getLength();

            //get the required element from each item
            for(int j=1;  j<clength; j=j+2){

                Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);

                String theString;
                String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();
                theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                Log.i("('-')ChildNode--->"+nodeName+"="+j+"---",theString.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}`
```